# All otf fonts stopped to be shown with Clear Type

Tags: windows-7

All otf (OpenType) fonts stopped to be shown with ClearType (subpixel) technology in ALL applications under Windows 7. This is only under one user. Under a new user all is OK.

TTF fonts are unaffected and always shown with ClearType. What should I do to restore the correct appearance?